# find indices of maximum value in matrix (python)

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, max

I want to find the indices[i,j] of the maximum value in a 2d numpy array:

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,3,1]])
```

I tried to do it using numpy.argsort() but it returns an array because it can be done along an axis only.
One solution can be by comparing elements at all indices (along both axes) returned by argsort using for loops, but it seems kind of complicated for this. Maybe there is a simple solution?

Comment: Does `a.argmax(1)` get you what you want?

Comment: @JonClements it returns array([2, 0], dtype=int64), Im not sure what that means. Fo rthis question, the result should be (1,0) because the max element is 4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html). The [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) will return an index as if the flattened version of array is traversed. The `unravel_index` will give you the `N-D` indices.

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (4,4))
ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(a, axis=None), a.shape)  # returns a tuple
```

Comment: simple, compact and exactly what I want! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can return what you are looking for? It returns the index of the max (

```
max_xy = np.where(a == a.max() )
```

Zip the result to get the index as list of tuples:

```
zip(max_xy[0], max_xy[1]) #=> [(1, 0)]
```

In case of more than one max: `a = np.array([[4,2,3],[4,3,4]])`, it returns `#=> [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2)]`

To return as a tuple the first maximum found, just fetch the first element of the array:

```
zip(max_xy[0], max_xy[1])[0] #=> (0, 0)
```

Comment: Yes it gives me the right answer. However, a slight problem. When I zip it, I get this: (array([1], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))
I don't exactly get the tuple [(1,0)]